# Executing without step definition of BUT

Tags: specflow

I faced an issue. We need to have a matching step definition for 'BUT' otherwise the execution is not happening. Based on reading Ben comments , i thought that it will not be required to have a matching step definition for 'BUT' but this is not the case.

Can we execute without having step definition provided 'BUT' is there ??

Comment: who is Ben? And where are his comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All steps must have a matching step definition. There are only 3 types of steps: `Given`, `When` and `Then`. `And` steps and `But` steps are just aliases for 'the same as the previous step'.  There is no attribute for `And` and `But`.

so these two scenarios are equivalent:

```
Given a given step
And some other given condition
When a thing happens
Then a condition should be true
But some other condition should not be
```

And

```
Given a given step
Given some other given condition
When a thing happens
Then a condition should be true
Then some other condition should not be
```

but obviously the first one reads a bit better

Comment: Thanks @sam for description. It has cleared my doubts.

Comment: @sunnybhatia great, I'm glad I could help. As you are a new user I would advise you to take some time to learn [how the site works](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [why voting and accepting answers is important](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)